# Are all "A PHP Error was encountered" issues?

Tags: manual-testing

Imagine I'm a "pure QA" without coding knowledge, found several "A PHP Error was encountered" message by normal test and very un-normal test. Are all these PHP errors, issues?, just need to make sure.

The Error message is like this one, any data/content that I already deleted as admin and then access it as user shows PHP Error message

[image]

Comment: We will need more contextual background to reach a suggestion, whether an issue is an issue depends on lots of factors. Please tell us more

Comment: Give us more details, if possible a scenario!

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, my bad....

It's something like this, As admin I delete a content on a menu such information list, then as a user at the same time I accessed on that information which is already deleted (By manual click or using a URL), A PHP error message appear. I assumed a message such "Your data doesn't exist" or "Result can't be found" should appear, I'm I right?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error? Just need to know if its a default error message or a custom message. Would be a good help to come up with an answer! You can edit the question to add more details and append images, etc!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking the scenario you have mentioned into consideration where you have deleted an item from the menu and a user is trying to access that item,

Or for that matter in any scenario, error message like the ones displaying in the screenshot you have shared should never get displayed in the front-end (user side).

The error message is giving away critical information which can be exploited by malicious users. Although such details can be of good help to developers for debugging and fixing problems, users don't need to see it.

Instead of allowing default PHP warning and error messages in the front-end a custom message should be displayed like the ones you have suggested in your comment.

OR

Redirect a user to a custom 404 Error page (Page not found) as per the scenario you have mentioned. For all the system and environment generated errors there should be a custom message or a custom error page. Never allow default error pages and messages to display in the front-end.

Comment: "Never allow default error pages and messages to display in the frontend", thank's in advance, that's really convinced me